# Extracting a string on a file that gets randomly edited

Tags: php, file-io

So, lets say that I have a text file that contains some information on a client.

```
Name=RichardBaxton
Age=21
Nicks=ReconRoverRick
Company=MorganIndustries
```

Obviously there are better ways to store information about people, but for the sake of the situation, I'll say that I'm a stubborn idiot who wants it to be like this.

What I am trying to do is extract the "ReconRoverRick" part, and put it in a string (Lets say, `$nick`). However, since the file is always changing, and it always changes at random, I have no clue on how to do this. The `Nicks=ReconRoverRick` part could change to `Nicks=KingBax` or something.

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file you're parsing is very similar format to an ini file.

You could try using php's built-in function `parse_ini_file` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php))

Example:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file('path/to/your/file.txt');
echo $ini_array['Nicks']; // will output ReconRoverRick/KingBax
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (preg_match("/^Nicks=(.+)$/", "Nicks=ReckonRoverRick", $matches)) { print $matches[1]; }`

Instead of `"Nicks=ReckonRoverRick"` use `file_get_contents("filename.txt")` where filename.txt is the name of the text-file containing this information.

Comment: Alright, this is a step in the right direction, but it still isn't working for me at all.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question/situation. You have a web server with that PHP script. Now on that web server you have, let's say, `client.txt` in the same directory as the PHP script with said contents. What you want to do is read in that text file (as it might have changed) and filter out the "Nicks"-Line. Is that correct?

Comment: I still don't know what's wrong about `if (preg_match("/^Nicks=(.+)$/", file_get_contents("filename.txt"), $matches)) { print $matches[1]; }`? It reads the file filename.txt, looks for a line `Nicks=...` and stores the `...` in `$matches[1]`, whatever `...` is - ReckonRoverRick, KingBax or anything else. So what do you need?